# Class can not be created

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new in ActionScript, and I'm trying to make my first application. I have a main class - subclass of `Sprite`. and another one class, wich should manage some evnts, like keyboard's key pressing. Here is it's initialisation:

```
private var controller:GameObjectController;
...
controller = new GameObjectController(this);
```

Here is `controller:GameObjectController` itself:

```
public class GameObjectController extends InteractiveObject
{
    var textField:TextField;

    public function GameObjectController(mainSprite: Sprite)
    {
    addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

    textField = new TextField();
    textField.text = "Hello, World";
    mainSprite.addChild(textField);
    }

    private function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent):void
    {
    textField.text = event.keyCode.toString();
    }

}
```

but when I'm trying to run this, I have an error:

> ArgumentError: Error #2012: Class GameObjectController$ can not be
>   created.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs: [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html)

> The InteractiveObject class itself does not include any APIs for
>   rendering content onscreen. To create a custom subclass of the
>   InteractiveObject class, extend one of the subclasses that do have
>   APIs for rendering content onscreen, such as the Sprite, SimpleButton,
>   TextField, or MovieClip classes.

So I would suggest trying to subclass Sprite instead and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: beat me to it with the quote ;)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, dont extend InteractiveObject. As the API says:

> The InteractiveObject class itself does not include any APIs for rendering content onscreen. To create a custom subclass of the InteractiveObject class, extend one of the subclasses that do have APIs for rendering content onscreen, such as the Sprite, SimpleButton, TextField, or MovieClip classes.

so instead use (eg):

```
public class GameObjectController extends Sprite
{
    ....
}
```

Secondly, arguments for the constructor need to be the same as the extended class - for display classes, that means zero arguments.

Comment: "arguments for the constructor need to be the same as the extended class" - this is definitely false, constructor can have any parameters, you just have to call `super()` with parameters it expects, everything else is up to your wishes.

Answer (score 1):

[flash.display.InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html) is an abstract class that can not be subclassed.  Instead, extend from [flash.display.Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html).

Don't forget to import Sprite and place your code in a package:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class GameObjectController extends Sprite
    {
        var textField:TextField;

        public function GameObjectController(mainSprite: Sprite)
        {
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

            textField = new TextField();
            textField.text = "Hello, World";
            mainSprite.addChild(textField);
        }

        private function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            textField.text = event.keyCode.toString();
        }
    }
}
```